# Trying to calculate and display the name and highest number of orders of agent with order status as final from order table and user from user table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT assignedTo, count(*)
FROM orders e,users d
WHERE e.assignedTo = d.id
GROUP BY d.id HAVING count(*) = (SELECT MAX(mycount) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as mycount FROM orders WHERE orderStatus='FINAL' GROUP BY assignedToAgent ORDER BY assignedToAgent) a)
```

This query gives me result if I remove the orderStatus='FINAL' condition from, but I need only final orders.

Comment: `HAVING` not needed, it seems that `ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1` is enough...

Answer (score 2):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

From what I can see, you don't even need a `JOIN`.  All the information is in `ORDERS`.  And then you can use window functions:

```
select o.assignto, o.cnt
from (select assignto, count(*) as cnt,
             max(count(*)) over () as max_cnt
      from orders o
      group by assignto
     ) o
where cnt = max_cnt;
```

Comment: all information is not in order table, i need agent name and category which are in user table, order table only contains agent id as assignedTo

Comment: @KuldeepSingh . . . That is not in your question.

Comment: Could you please look into this?